# Android - app not searchable in Android store

Tags: android

I have a new app that I made and put in the store yesterday.

I am able to see it here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.problemio

but there is absolutely no way I can see it in the app store when I search for any terms.  Any idea how I can get it to show up in the app store?

It says that the app IS compatible with my phone so I don't see why it wouldn't show up for me.

Comment: searching for the app title in a browser gives your app as third item. Additionally: this is not a programming question. I suggest moving it to android.stackexchange.com

Comment: yesterday i couldn't find it, and it did not support my phone. Today i found it, and it supports it.

Comment: I can see it on my device (Galaxy Nexus), so presumably its an issue with your region or your deivce; but I agree with stefan; this is an Android issue rather than a coding one.

Comment: @Th0rndike and HaemEternal how did you search for it? Thanks!

Comment: This is a coding issue, this is caused by the filters or permissions that are set in the applications manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons an application might be filtered for a given device. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html) is a good article that explains how the market will filter applications from a given device. You might want to read through that to find why you are not seeing the application. If the application is up on the website than it has been posted on the market so your app is being filtered for some reason.